# VBA excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA macro in Excel. When a user clicks on a button on the sheet the macro returns the results to the sheet.
 What i would like to ask,is how can i run more than one query (that returns different results) in the same sheet,using the below code?

```
Sub Stats2()
  Workbooks("macro.xls").Sheets("Sheet3").Select
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

  Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim strSQL As String
  szconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=*******88;Data Source=****"

  ''#Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
  Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset

  On Error GoTo errHandler

  ''#Open the Connection and execute the stored procedure
  objConn.Open szconnect
  strSQL = "select * from CATEGORY_TYPE  "
  objConn.CommandTimeout = 0
  Set rsData = objConn.Execute(strSQL)

  For iCols = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + iCols).Value = rsData.Fields(iCols).Name
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Font.Name = "Arial"
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Font.Size = 8
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Next

  ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + rsData.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
  j = 2

  If Not rsData.EOF Then
    ''#Dump the contents of the recordset onto the worksheet
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    If Not rsData.EOF Then
      MsgBox "Data set too large for a worksheet!"
    End If
    rsData.Close 
  End If

  Unload frmSQLQueryADO
  Exit Sub

  errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error No: " & Err.Number
    ''#Unload frmSQLQueryADO
End Sub
```

Comment: you could call multiple methods from the one method and each method performs it's own logic.  I'm not sure I understand this question.

Comment: what i mean is in this section of code 
    strSQL = "select * from ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_TYPE  "

how do i add another query? can i add it like this strSQL = "select * from ACCOUNT_CATEGORY_TYPE  "+ "select * from users"  ?

Comment: You will need to clarify the Q then. Why do you want to run multiples querys? Do you realize that there is no logic in the return set of your example in the comment?

Comment: refined...the reason for i want to run multible queries is because these queries return different results.

Answer (score 1):

You should call exactly this procedure from a superior one, pass the query and the starting cell as parameters and you can run it several times filling the sheet like you want.

little example:

```
sub stats2()
    dim lastrow as string
    lastrow = "A1"
    lastrow = Query1(lastrow,"select * from foo")
    lastrow = Query1(lastrow,"select * from other")
end sub

sub query1(startingrow as string, sqlquery as string) as string
    'your code here. Take in mind that you can have a connection opened outside of here
    'The rest could be the same
    'just use the two parameters, one for the query, the other for the range you 
    'start filling the columns name.
    [code here]
    'return the las used row.
end sub
```

Comment: ermmm ok can you give me an examle on how to do this..not realy a VB progrmammer here..

Answer (score 0):

IF you can set the queries up in a stored procedure on the SQL server the queries will be executed an seperated result sets returned, something like:

```
   Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command

    With oCmd
        .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "SprocName"
    End With

    Set rsData = oCmd.Execute()

    'do stuff with the first results

    rsData.NextRecordset
    'rsData will now be the next set of results

    rsData.NextRecordset
    'rsData will now be the third set of results
```

Alternatively you may be able to specify multiple queries with

```
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = "Select * FROM Foo; Select * FROM Bar;"
```

having the ; between each query, I'm not sure about this, I usually set up a sproc